# How to add a footnote under the x-axis of a plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot-annotations

I couldn't find the right function to add a footnote in my plot.

The footnote I want to have is something like an explanation of one item in the legend, but it is too long to put in the legend box. So, I'd like to add a ref number, e.g. [1], to the legend item, and add the footnote in the bottom of the plot, under the x-axis.

Which function should I use?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

One way would be just use `plt.text(x,y,'text')`

Comment: Oh, you are right, I forgot this... I will see if I could add it under the x-axis. Cheers.

Comment: `plt.annotate` makes this much easier than `plt.text`.  `annotate` lets you work in axis or figure coordinates instead of just data coordinates.  It's easy to (for example) put text 20 _points_ below the left side of the x-axis.  `plt.annotate('Something', (0,0), (0, -20), xycoords='axes fraction', textcoords='offset points', va='top')`

Comment: I use plt.figtext(0.99, 0.01, 'footnote text', horizontalalignment='right')

Comment: @MarkGraph has a great solution.

Comment: No OOP interface?

Comment: @JoeKington This gets cut off.

Comment: a solution using the OOP interface would be ideal, seeing as that is what the docs suggest to use

Answer (score 24):

You would be just use:

```
plt.figtext(0.5, 0.01, "one text and next text", ha="center", fontsize=18, bbox={"facecolor":"orange", "alpha":0.5, "pad":5})
```

[image]

Comment: good... why doesn't axes.figtext() not work?