# Rotating part of xticks

Tags: python, matplotlib

On the x-axis, I would like to display numbers (with no rotation) with rotated names below each number. I have the following but would like to separately rotate the names 'one', 'two' and 'three'.

```
plt.xticks([1,2,3], ['1\n one', '2\n two', '3\n three'], rotation=45]
```

Comment: What's `plt`? Are you using some kind of library?

Comment: @Kevin: a very valid question, but I think it is save to assume that the OP uses *matplotlib*

Comment: Apologies, I should have included the line: `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can place major and minor ticks at the same positions. Here is a minimum example:

```py
import pylab as pl

pl.clf()
ax = pl.gca()
ax.set_xticks([1, 2, 3])
ax.set_xticks([1, 2, 3], minor=True)
ax.set_xticklabels(['one', 'two', 'three'], minor=True)
pl.setp(ax.xaxis.get_minorticklabels(), rotation=-45)

for t in ax.get_xticklabels(minor=True):
    t.set_y(-0.03)
```

[image]

(With some inspiration from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20546657/3419103).)