# Matplotlib plotting from grouped dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot

My pandas dataframe is in two time dimensions, the `date` and the `period` the data fall in. Making a pivot table out of it further explains the structure. But how to plot a line chart along the two time dimensions

```
raw_data = {'period': ['2016-05-26', '2016-05-26', '2016-05-26', '2016-05-27', '2016-05-27'],
    'date': ['2016-05-26', '2016-05-27', '2016-05-28', '2016-05-26', '2016-05-27'],
    'mid_score': [25, 94, 57, 62, 70],
    'post_score': [5, 43, 23, 23, 51]}
df = pd.DataFrame(raw_data, columns = ['period', 'date', 'mid_score', 'post_score'])
df
```

[image]

```
df.groupby(['period','date']).sum()
```

[image]

What is the best way to plot this kind of grouped data, is it possible to have it like this kind of line chart?

[image]

Comment: I think the easiest is use `df.groupby(['period','date']).sum().plot()`. But there is problem with values in axis x. You get tuples, because after groupby you get multiindex.

Comment: you may want to check this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20546657/5741205)

Comment: Building on @jezrael's comment, you can modify the dataframe's index to get the tick labels you want. For instance: `df.groupby(['period','date']).sum().reset_index(level=0, drop=True).plot()`. However, I'm not sure why you have repeating dates.

Comment: @jezrael x-axis tuples would be difficult to visualize for many values of x-axis

Comment: Exactly, and it is not nice.

Comment: But @DevEx you have only one date on the x-axis in the example you showed. Which is it, `period` or `date`?

Comment: @IanS the example shows how x-axes can be grouped, year is first level, month is the second level. In my own case, period is the first level, date is the second level, and the aggregation term is sum