# Fix overlapping of X-axis values on Matplotlib graph

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, graph, statistics

I need some help with my Matplotlib graph. The project can be viewed [here](https://github.com/SpiritedByte/COVID-19_Project/tree/new_graphs) (currently working under the new-graph branch).

As a summary of what this project does:

- Download two CSV files (UK COVID-19 cases and UK COVID-19 deaths)
- Parse the CSV files as a Pandas data-frame to only have the columns with the date and the cumulative values
- Plot these two sets of data on one graph using Matplotlib bar graph

My issue is that Matplotlib is not automatically spacing out the X-axis values (the dates). I'm not sure if it's because Matplotlib does not recognise them as dates or some other error I've made.
[Here is what the graph currently looks like.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Ic9S.png)

EDIT:
Sorry I forgot to add the code to the question. Here it is...

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def plot(cases,deaths):
    #cases.plot(x='Specimen date',y='Cumulative lab-confirmed cases',color='green')
    #deaths.plot(x='Reporting date',y='Cumulative deaths',color='red')
    plt.figure("Cumulative deaths and cases")
    ax = plt.gca()
    cases.plot(kind='bar', x='Specimen date', y='Cumulative lab-confirmed cases',ax=ax, color='green')
    deaths.plot(kind='bar', x='Reporting date', y='Cumulative deaths', ax=ax, color='red')
    plt.show()
```

Comment: Please include your code in the body of the question to make it easier for people to help you.

Comment: Completely forgot about that. I've fixed it now, sorry!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you have far too many tick labels for the size of the plot.

I recommend spacing the ticks, such that it fits in your plot. This can be done with `set_xticks`, from `Axis.axis`. For instance, in the example below I am including a tick every 5 occurrences.

For improving readability further, I also included a rotation of 45 degrees on the tick labels. Note the parameter `ha="right"` there. It is used to make sure the right part of the label is the one aligned with the tick.

```
def plot(cases, deaths):
    plt.figure("Cumulative deaths and cases")
    ax = plt.gca()
    cases.plot(kind='bar', x='Specimen date', y='Cumulative lab-confirmed cases', ax=ax, color='green')
    deaths.plot(kind='bar', x='Reporting date', y='Cumulative deaths', ax=ax, color='red')
   
    ax.xaxis.set_ticks(range(0, len(cases), 5))
    ax.set_xticklabels(ax.get_xticklabels(), rotation=45, ha="right")

    plt.show()
```

Answer (score -1):

You probably want to make the xticks smaller using this function:
`plt.xticks(fontsize=desired_size)`

Comment: Hi there, thanks for the reply. That seems to be a good workaround if I increase the size of the window. Is there a way I could space them out? E.g. 21/03/2020 ... 23/03/2020 ... (instead of them all being along the axis?)

Comment: @SpiritedByte You can use the parameter `rotation` in the `plt.xticks()` function to make the ticks horizontal if that is what you want. If you want the ticks to be on multiple lines, maybe this post is useful [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20532614/multiple-lines-of-x-tick-labels-in-matplotlib).