# Create dynamic footnote text in matplotlib

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, plot

I would like to be able to add footnote text similar to the following in matplotlib:

[image]

The following code will create a plot with similar text

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd


fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize = (5, 8))
n = 10
np.random.seed(1)
_ = ax.scatter(np.random.randint(0, 10, n), np.random.randint(0, 10, n), s=500)
x = 0
y = 1
_ = ax.text(
    x, y, "hello this is some text at the bottom of the plot", fontsize=15, color="#555"
)
```

Which looks as:

[image]

However, if the data changes then the above won't adjust, such as:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd


fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(5, 8))

n = 10
np.random.seed(2)
_ = ax.scatter(np.random.randint(0, 10, n), np.random.randint(0, 10, n), s=500)
x = 0
y = 1
_ = ax.text(
    x, y, "hello this is some text at the bottom of the plot", fontsize=15, color="#555"
)
```

[image]

I have [seen this question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7918549/3130747), and this just says how to plot text at a particular `x,y` coordinate. I specifically want to be able to set a footnote though, not plot at a particular x,y, so the solution should be dynamic.

Also, use of the OOP interface is preferred as [mentioned in the docs](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/index.html#the-pyplot-api).

*Note* - there seems to be issues with the current suggestion when using `fig.tight_layout()`

Comment: As a sidenote, if you don't need the return values of `ax.scatter` and `ax.text`, you don't need to assign them to a variable at all.

Comment: @mapf i have added imports for you - also - i know i don't need them, I just assign them so i don't get output in jupyterlab

Answer (score 2):

You should try plotting the text relative to the subplot and not relative to the points in the subplot using `transform=ax.transAxes`. You should also set the alignment so that the text starts based on the location you want. The can play around with the point location.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd


fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(5, 8))

n = 10
np.random.seed(2)
_ = ax.scatter(np.random.randint(0, 10, n), np.random.randint(0, 10, n), s=500)
x = 0
y = -.07
ax.text(x, y, "hello this is some text at the bottom of the plot", fontsize=15, 
        horizontalalignment='left',verticalalignment='top', transform=ax.transAxes)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: this seems to have problems when using `fig.tight_layout()`

Comment: Do you need `fig.tight_layout()`? You are adjusting the axis so the numbers you choose don't have the same meaning. See https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/tight_layout_api.html

Comment: Do you change the layout before or after you plot the text?